Setting extent for screenshot via PyQGIS
I am trying to figure out how I can set the extent of the rendered image because with QgsMapSettings().setExtent it doesn't work for me.
How can I set the extent as big as the biggest active vector layer?
vlayer = captured_layers_i
settings = QgsMapSettings()
settings.setLayers(vlayer)
settings.setOutputSize(QSize(1000,1000))
settings.setExtent(vlayer[0].extent())
settings.setDestinationCrs(vlayer[0].crs())
settings.setDpiTarget(300)

render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)

def finished(layer_name=layer_name):
    img = render.renderedImage()
    # save the image; e.g. img.save("/Users/myuser/render.png","png")
    img.save(os.path.join("C:/temp", f"{layer_name}.png"), "png")

render.finished.connect(finished)

# Start the rendering
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
render.start()
render.waitForFinished()


What is the captured_layers_i ? Can you please describe in which way it doesn't work for me ? Did you try to measure the areas of vector layer extents ?

It is a list with the layers inside, i want to capture in the screenshot.
setExtent does not work insofar as the section of the saved image is significantly larger than I want it to be.

So what i want to reach is the Setting to calculate the extent out of a layer like in the image export of the canvas.
I want to reach the marked setting in this picture: https://i.postimg.cc/xddTjrd8/image.png

QgsMapSettings.setExtent() works as expected you just need to select the right extent or build it depending on your needs. All your extents need to be in the same CRS to be compared easily so they need to be reprojected to a common CRS.
Here are two versions, one with the biggest extent:
settings.setExtent(max(extents, key=lambda x: x.area()))

And another with the combined extent of all layer extents:
settings.setExtent(QgsGeometry.collectGeometry([QgsGeometry.fromRect(extent) for extent in extents]).boundingBox())

project = QgsProject.instance()
vlayer = list(project.mapLayers().values())

settings = QgsMapSettings()
settings.setLayers(vlayer)
settings.setOutputSize(QSize(1000,1000))

extents = [
    layer.extent() 
    if layer.crs() == project.crs() 
    else QgsCoordinateTransform(
        layer.crs(),
        project.crs(), 
        project.transformContext()
    ).transformBoundingBox(layer.extent())
    
    for layer in vlayer
    # If you want to use a base map like openstreet map 
    # you need to exclude it from the extents otherwise the png will zoom
    # out to display the entire basemap raster extent (the entire world)
    if layer.name() != "openstreetmap"
]

settings.setExtent(max(extents, key=lambda x: x.area()))

# settings.setExtent(QgsGeometry.collectGeometry([QgsGeometry.fromRect(extent) for extent in extents]).boundingBox())

settings.setDestinationCrs(project.crs())
settings.setDpiTarget(300)

render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)

def finished(layer_name="layer"):
    img = render.renderedImage()
    # save the image; e.g. img.save("/Users/myuser/render.png","png")
    img.save(os.path.join("C:/temp",f"{layer_name}.png"), "png")

render.finished.connect(finished)

# Start the rendering
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
render.start()
render.waitForFinished()


Thank you, that helped a lot!

Please remember what you should do when someone answers your question
